# window.location.hash is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, hash

I am calling window.location.hash On body onload and passing a value to it as follows:

```
<body onload="displayView('wc001');"/>

<script>

function displayView(sectionName)
{
    window.location.hash=sectionName
}
</script>
```

We even incldued the anchor tag for wc001 inside the body.

Its not working fine in IE11
Its working fine in chrome,ie7.
Is there any alternative code for window.location.hash to put in IE11   compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue with IE11. The solution is-
Instead of using anchor tag as a bookmark to the particular location, set the "id" attribute of the HTML elements like

, etc. with the name of the required anchor.

```
<!-- <a name="wc001"></a> -->
<p id="wc001">Section to scroll to</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I justed tested this in IE.

```
 window.location.hash = hashName;
```

If this really doesn't work then we could use scrollIntoView.

```
 function scrollToAnchor(anchorName){
   //set the hash so people can bookmark
   window.location.hash = anchorName;
   //scroll the anchor into view
   document.getElementsByName(anchorName)[0].scrollIntoView(true);
 }
```

Use like this:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>scrollIToAnchor('foo');</script>
 <a name='foo'></a>
 <p>I will be scrolled into view</p>
```